# How to pass data from AngularJS form to struts 2 action class?

Tags: angularjs, spring

Here I am developing shopping cart. This is my AngularJS controller. This method use to send data to action 
class using $http.post method

```
 angular.module("sportsStore")
.constant("dataUrl", "angularAction")
.constant("orderUrl", "angularSaveAction")
.controller("sportsStoreCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $location,
                                         dataUrl, orderUrl, cart) {
 enter code here`$scope.data = {
    };
    $scope.sendOrder = function (shippingDetails) {
        var order = angular.copy(shippingDetails);    
        order.products = cart.getProducts();
        console.log(order);--------------(1)
        $http.post(orderUrl, order)
            .success(function (data) {
                //$scope.items=data;
                $scope.data.orderId = data.id;
                cart.getProducts().length = 0;
                console.log(data);---------------(2)
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $scope.data.orderError = error;
            }).finally(function () {
                $location.path("/complete");
            });
    }});
```

Using (1) console.log i confirm all form data and shopping cart detail stoed array.But (2) console log is Null
This is my Action class

```
   package com.ai.action;
   import com.ai.model.PersonData;
   import com.ai.model.Product;
   import com.ai.model.ProductOrder;
   import com.ai.model.Village;
   import com.ai.service.PersonService;
   import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;
   import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
   import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

   import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;
   import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.ActionMapping;
   import org.slf4j.Logger;

  public class OrderAction extends 
    ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<ProductOrder> {--------------(1)

  private Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
  private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AngularAction.class);

  private List<ProductOrder> order;-------------(2)

  private ProductOrder productOrder;

  @Autowired
  private PersonService  personService;

public String execute()

{
    getOrder();
    logger.info("this method ic" ,order);
    //personService.save(personService);----------(3)
    return SUCCESS;
}

public List<ProductOrder> getOrder() {
    return order;
}

public void setOrder(List<ProductOrder> order) {
    this.order = order;
}

@Override
public ProductOrder getModel() {
    return productOrder;
}

 }
```

How I get form data 
 Can I use 
ModleDriven(1) or 
List array(2) or any method. I want save this form data in mysql database using hibernate(3).please help me....
How I get form data 
 Can I use 
ModleDriven(1) or 
List array(2) or any method. I want save this form data in mysql database using hibernate(3).please help me....

Comment: Please help  me very argent...